# Cities, roads, and net traffic. Group/Aggregate one table by an index column in another?

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, merge, aggregate

I've got a DataFrame called `cities` with an index of `city_name` and a column labeled `net_traffic`, and another table called `roads` with columns `from_city`, `to_city`, and `traffic_cars_per_hour`.

A road may only connect a `from_city` to a `to_city`; however, a city may have many roads leading to and from it.

**I would like to sum/aggregate the net traffic in and out of each `city` in my `cities` table.** My first attempt was something along the lines of:

```
cities.net_traffic  = 0
cities.net_traffic += roads.groupby('to_city').traffic_cars_per_hour.sum()
cities.net_traffic -= roads.groupby('from_city').traffic_cars_per_hour.sum()
```

Which just gave me `Nan`s

How would I go about this in Python Pandas?

**Example**

```
import pandas as pd

cities = pd.DataFrame({
    'city_name':   ['chicago', 'new_york', 'los_angeles'],
    'net_traffic': [0, 0, 0]
})

roads = pd.DataFrame({
    'from_city': ['chicago', 'chicago', 'new_york'], 
    'to_city':   ['new_york', 'los_angeles', 'los_angeles'],
    'traffic_cars_per_hour': [10, -10, 5]
})
```

Expected output.

```
cities 
city_name    net_traffic
chicago       0
new_york      5
los_angeles  -5
```

Comment: Elaborate a small example showing a sample of both DataFrames and the expected output, so we can clearly understand what you want and reproduce it.

Answer (score 1):

(Using some other examples I came up, before your edit, ...)
A very lengthy, explicit and step-by-step fashion to solve this problem could be:

```
import pandas as pd

# "cities": ["Hamburg", "London", "Paris", "New York", "Berlin"]
example: dict = {"from": ["Hamburg", "Hamburg", "Hamburg", "London",   "London", "New York", "Paris",  "Paris"],
                 "to":   ["London",  "Paris",   "Berlin",  "New York", "Paris",  "Berlin",   "Berlin", "New York"],
                 "cars_per_hour": [20, 10, 30, 50, 100, 40, 10, 30]}

df_traffic = pd.DataFrame().from_dict(example)
df_traffic_from = df_traffic.groupby("from").sum().reset_index()
df_traffic_to = df_traffic.groupby("to").sum().reset_index()

# distinct city values: 
df_cities = pd.DataFrame()
df_cities["city"] = pd.concat([df_traffic_from["from"], df_traffic_to["to"]]).unique()

# calculate incoming/outgoing traffic per city
incoming = pd.merge(left=df_cities, right=df_traffic_to, left_on="city", right_on="to", how="outer").drop(columns="to").rename(columns={"cars_per_hour":"incoming"})

traffic = pd.merge(left=incoming, right=df_traffic_from, left_on="city", right_on="from", how="outer").drop(columns="from").rename(columns={"cars_per_hour":"outgoing"})

# replace NaN values with zero
traffic = traffic.fillna(0)
traffic.head()

# calculate net traffic
traffic["net_traffic"] = traffic.incoming - traffic.outgoing
traffic.head()
```

[results table for traffic per city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uH6Q5.png)

Again: This is probably an EXTREMLY inefficient solution, but I think it's most illustrative.

Best regards,
Sören

Comment: This answer has got me thinking. Seems like the right approach _is_ to group by on the `roads`  table first, and the later merge back into the `cities` table. Wish there was a cleaner way to do it though!